# docker_compose v2 volume container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm making a simple docker_compose.yml file to launch a jenkins2 server with a separated named volume for data.

The 1st script, without the volume **works fine**:

```
version : '2'
services:
    jkm:
        image: jenkins
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
            - "50000:50000"
```

After that I wanted to add a named volume, and read the cocumentation here:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

**important to note this is a v2 file** so following the doc there should be **no `volume_from`**

Here is the script i made:

```
version : '2'
services:
    jkm:
        image: jenkins
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
            - "50000:50000"
        volumes: 
            - jkd:/var/jenkins_home
volumes:
    jkd:{}
```

when i run `docker-compose up`i get this error

> volume must be a mapping, not a string

jdk, is a mapping; and so the string i guessed was /var/jenkins_home.

I've tried a lot of slight versions of this, but whatever i put, i always get this kind of error, and i don't see where i should have a mapping. 
I've done this trying to follow that: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volume-configuration-reference

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
version : '2'
services:
  jkm:
      image: jenkins
      ports:
          - "8080:8080"
          - "50000:50000"
      volumes: 
          - jkd:/var/jenkins_home
volumes:
  jkd: # named volume
```

Don't add the curly braces to the volume declaration.

Comment: Thank you i had folow this: which used it.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#upgrading 

It works thanks

Comment: Any clue as to why this solves the problem - or what the intent of the curly braces is?